# I want the background of panel scroll in unity5

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I make a scene in unity5 with Canvas and added Panel into that canvas,I want to scroll background image of panel but could not find any reasonable solution for this, I know background scrolling is applied to quad, but I want to do it with panel, is it possible or guide me best possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ScrollRect` to scroll the Panel.[This may help](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/39297-how+to+make+a+scrollable+panel+using+the+4.6+unity+ui.pdf)

Comment: but I want to make an image scroll infinitely in the background of the panel

Comment: Make an animation and set the wrapMode to Loop